# NHibernate Session in global.asax Application_BeginRequest

Tags: c#, wcf, nhibernate

I am trying to start a hibernate session in Global.asax and Application_BeginRequest and then access a static SessionFactory on Global.asax to get the current session in a WCF service.

However I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when I try to get the current session inside the service. I am accessing the service using basicHttpBinding.

Global.asax

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
        public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory { get; private set; }

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Initialize session factory and set up mappings
        }


        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession();
            CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);
        }

        protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var session = CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(SessionFactory);
            if (session != null)
            {
                if (session.Transaction != null &&
                    session.Transaction.IsActive)
                {
                    session.Transaction.Rollback();
                }
                else
                    session.Flush();
                session.Close();
            }
        }

}
```

MyService.svc

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
   public void doStuff()
   {
      //Exception occurs here. Session Factory is not null. But GetCurrentSession() gives exception.
      ISession session = Global.SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();

   }
}
```

Hibernate Config

```
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect</property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">...</property>
      <property name="current_session_context_class">web</property>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: why are you always rolling back your transaction in EndRequest? Nothing is ever going to get saved.

Comment: If there is a transaction still active that hasn't been committed it will be rolled back. This is in case there was an uncaught exception during a transaction. Otherwise there are no uncommitted transactions and the session will be flushed.

Comment: If you are hosting in the Web then your commit logic should be in there.  The Web request is the unit of work.  You shouldn't have an explicit call to commit in your code.  There's also a wcf context class that you aren't using.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `<property name="current_session_context_class">web</property>` to `<property name="current_session_context_class">call</property>` after seeing this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nhusers/jo9TJOKXWlI
and it is working