# Must I use Eager loading if the session is disposed of?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, domain-driven-design

Please see the code below:

```
public Enquiry GetByID(Guid personID)
{
    using (IUnitOfWork<ISession> unitOfWork = UnitOfWorkFactory.Create())
    {
        IRepository repository = RepostioryFactory.Create(unitOfWork);
        var Person = repository.GetById(personID);
        return Person;
    }
}
```

It is contained in an application service layer.  Person is passed back to the Controller and loaded into a view.  The view then errors because it cannot load Person.Collection (a list).

I believe this is because the collection is loaded using lazy loading and the unit of work and NHibernate session is closed once the view is reached.  Must I use eager loading in this situation or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO lazy loading is evil!

The idea behind a repository is to return an aggregate.  That aggregate should contain *all* the relevant data that constitute the aggregate.  It is never loaded in bits.  An aggregate should, therefore, always be eagerly fetched.

If you remove UoW/ORM from the equation lazy loading just isn't an option.

You should try *not* to query your domain.  If you have a situation where a single aggregate contains all the data you need and that data has been exposed then that would be OK.

However, I would recommend you use a read model.  A simple query layer.  Give that a try and you may just be surprised :)

Comment: +1 for lazy-loading is evil statement. Spliting domain to read-write models is like a deposit with 100% interest rate, it gives you a full freedom to tune your queries

Comment: I agree with the cqrs read model (I assume you mean cqrs?).  However, uow is an established pattern.  Are you saying it should not be used with an orm? Is that just your opinion? Alternatively can you post a link that talks about avoiding uow with NHibernate?

Comment: It *may* be an established pattern but by its very definition the "unit of work" implies manipulating multiple objects as a batch.  This is something that one should attempt to avoid; although not *always* possible.  However, navigating through the domain model is problematic at best: `Order` to `OrderItem` to `Supplier` to `Address` to `City`... an aggregate really should be explicitly contained.  Most things I say are my opinion :) --- or a stolen one!  The session per request is the usual solution and if that works for you then it is ok but you are holding onto a DB connection a long time.

Answer (score 1):

I realized the session is ending before the method finishes (its wrapped in a `using` block), which is before your view code runs. So yes, you do need to eager load the items in the collection property in your `Enquiry` type you get back from the NHibernate session.

A better way is to setup the unit of work pattern so it wraps around the entire request in the pipeline. For example, if you have a `Global.asax` file, it has two methods called `Application_BeginRequest` and `Application_EndRequest`.

The `Application_BeginRequest` method would create a new NHibernate session which can be retrieved by your controllers.

The `Application_EndRequest` method would simply flush your session, saving any data changes to the underlying database.

I refer you to the following StackOverflow question for incorporating NHibernate sessions with the `Global.asax` component: [NHibernate Session in global.asax Application_BeginRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33090991/nhibernate-session-in-global-asax-application-beginrequest)

Comment: How does this answer my question? There is a member in the Person class called: Collection i.e. Person.Collection.

Answer (score 0):

Introducing a View Model layer instead of passing the raw entity over to the Controller will solve your problem since mapping to the `Person` View Model (inside the `using` clause) will access `Person.Collection` and trigger the loading.

Alternatively, you could have a whole Read side that doesn't go through the domain, as @EbenRoux suggests.

Answer (score 0):

> Must I use eager loading in this situation or am I misunderstanding something?

Well, you want to, don't you?  You are in a use case where you know that you want Person.Collection to be available, so why wouldn't you load it right away.

The trick is not to use the same repository implementation that you use when you want the collection to be loaded lazily (or not at all).

Udi Dahan wrote about this a number of times

- http://udidahan.com/2007/03/06/better-domain-driven-design-implementation/
- http://udidahan.com/2007/04/23/fetching-strategy-design/

Greg Young would caution you that the use of a fetching strategy is an implementation detail, and not part of the contract

- http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2009/01/16/ddd-the-generic-repository/

Comment: Say I wanted to use lazy loading for the code in my question (because the collection does not always have to be loaded ).  I can't using my code because the session is closed to soon.  Should I be using a session per web request?

Comment: Is it ok to load the session using Castle Windsor? Should the lifecycle be per request?